# Hide h4 on search

Tags: javascript, html, search

I want to hide the h4 heading on search of text.. I'm able to get the search but wanted to hide the h4 also.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<h4>Name List 1</h4>
<ol id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ol>

<h4>Name List 2</h4>
<ol id="myUL2">
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
</ol>

<h4>Name List 3</h4>
<ol id="myUL3">
  <li><a href="#">Anim</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bitto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ol>
```

I have the search option as mentioned below.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.querySelectorAll("ol li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to hide only those h4 heading which result not found ?

Comment: @Aish you just want hide `<h4>` or the complete block including last `<ol>` ?

Comment: complete actually, The script hides all. but not the h4

Comment: https://imgur.com/jDXECgH
This is what I get in return if I search, I wanted to hide Name List 1, 2, 3

Comment: you want to hide all h4 ? only those h4 which doesnot have result ?

Comment: All h4 i need to hide bro..

Comment: added answer @Asha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.querySelectorAll("ol li");
    var parent;
    var sibiling;
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
         Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("h4"), function(el) {
                    el.style.display = '';
                });
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
                                      Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("h4"), function(el) {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                });
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<h4>Name List 1</h4>
<ol id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ol>

<h4>Name List 2</h4>
<ol id="myUL2">
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
</ol>

<h4>Name List 3</h4>
<ol id="myUL3">
  <li><a href="#">Anim</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bitto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this is as expected or not.